# Customize the appearance of a <Key>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Some 3rd party keyboards have more than one character on each key, for example Better Keyboard 8 has numbers and punctuation above the letters on each key:

[image: Better Keyboard screen shot]

Can this be done with the `<Key>` tag? If so I cannot figure out how. I would appreciate if anybody knows how.

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured it out so I am answering my own question.

It cannot be done in XML, but it can be done in Java by overriding the onDraw() method of KeyboardView. This pointless example draws a small letter at the top of each key after the keys are drawn by the parent class:

```
public class MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setTextSize(25);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
        for(Key key: keys) {
            if(key.label != null)
                canvas.drawText(key.label.toString(), key.x + (key.width/2), key.y + 25, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!  How do you make the secondary characters appear below the key-text instead of above it?

Comment: Just tweak the 3rd value in drawText(). It controls the y-position. key.y is the bottom of the key relative to the bottom of the keyboard.

Comment: Hi @BarryFruitman my requirement same as shown in above keyboard, so i used the code given you in your answer post. But i am getting NullPointerException when i am calling drawText() method in onDraw() overriden method of View class.

Comment: Hi @BarryFruitman i have successfully displayed characters using onDraw() as you shown above but problem arises when i am creating keys using paint...i used drawRect()....but nothing helped me...so can you please tell me how can i create keys using paint as you shown above...

Comment: Sorry Aniket I cannot answer your question here. I suggest you post another question with a sample of your code. Good luck.

Comment: @BarryFruitman: My requirement was different, but this code helped me a lot.

Comment: but how to remove the text which i add from the qwerty.xml file in folder xml.