# How to change background color or theme of keys dynamically in Custom Keyboard Android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am working on Custom keyboard app I need to set or change background theme or color of keyboard .their setting.xml view in my app  where user can select different background theme and different color for key rows.
during first time launch of application it is working fine but next time when custom keyboard is displaying theme is not changed.

I am using this code:

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
static final boolean DEBUG = false;

/**
 * This boolean indicates the optional example code for performing
 * processing of hard keys in addition to regular text generation
 * from on-screen interaction.  It would be used for input methods that
 * perform language translations (such as converting text entered on 
 * a QWERTY keyboard to Chinese), but may not be used for input methods
 * that are primarily intended to be used for on-screen text entry.
 */
static final boolean PROCESS_HARD_KEYS = true;

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 101;

private KeyboardView mInputView;
private CandidateView mCandidateView;
private CompletionInfo[] mCompletions;
private Context context = SoftKeyboard.this;
private StringBuilder mComposing = new StringBuilder();
private boolean mPredictionOn;
private boolean mCompletionOn;
private int mLastDisplayWidth;
private boolean mCapsLock;
private long mLastShiftTime;
private long mMetaState;

private LatinKeyboard mSymbolsKeyboard;
private LatinKeyboard mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard;
private LatinKeyboard mQwertyKeyboard;
private LatinKeyboard mSmilyKeyboard;
private LatinKeyboard mSmilyKeyboard1;

private LatinKeyboard mCurKeyboard;

private String mWordSeparators;

/**
 * Main initialization of the input method component.  Be sure to call
 * to super class.
 */

@Override 
   public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mWordSeparators = getResources().getString(R.string.word_separators);      
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = preferences.getString("Name","");


    Log.e("SoftKeyboard - ",""+name+"OnCreate Method Called--");



    if(!name.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
      name = name+"  Sethi";  /* Edit the value here*/
    }
}
```

And This is my Setting Class where i am setting or selecting color or theme:

```
public class Setting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    LinearLayout roar, edge, burst, impact, blue_theme, orange_theme,
            green_theme, black_brigthness, white_brightness;

    Bundle bundle;

    public static boolean isblackBrightness = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);

        // ----------UI intilisation---------------------
        uiInitilisation();

    }

    public void uiInitilisation() {

        roar = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ror_LL);
        edge = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.edge_LL);
        burst = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.burst_LL);
        impact = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.impact_LL);

        // -------------Themes------------------------------
        blue_theme = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.blue_theme_LL);
        orange_theme = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.orange_theme_LL);
        green_theme = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.green_theme_LL);

        // ------------Brightness----------------------------
        black_brigthness = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.black_brigthness_LL);
        white_brightness = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.white_brigthness_LL);

        // --------------On Click Events-------------------

        roar.setOnClickListener(this);
        edge.setOnClickListener(this);
        burst.setOnClickListener(this);
        impact.setOnClickListener(this);

        // -----------Theme-------------------------------------
        blue_theme.setOnClickListener(this);
        orange_theme.setOnClickListener(this);
        green_theme.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ------------------Brightness--------------------------
        black_brigthness.setOnClickListener(this);
        white_brightness.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.ror_LL:

            startActivity(new Intent(Setting.this, MainActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.edge_LL:

            startActivity(new Intent(Setting.this, MainActivity.class));




            break;
        case R.id.burst_LL:

            startActivity(new Intent(Setting.this, MainActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.impact_LL:

            startActivity(new Intent(Setting.this, MainActivity.class));

            break;  

        case R.id.blue_theme_LL:

            Intent i = new Intent(Setting.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("color", "blue");

            startActivity(i);


            break;

        case R.id.orange_theme_LL:
            Intent i2 = new Intent(Setting.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
                i2.putExtra("color", "orange");

            startActivity(i2);

            break;

        case R.id.green_theme_LL:
            Intent i3 = new Intent(Setting.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
                i3.putExtra("color", "green");

            startActivity(i3);

            break;
        case R.id.black_brigthness_LL:

            Intent black_britness = new Intent(Setting.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            black_britness.putExtra("bright", "black");
            startActivity(black_britness);

              SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              editor.putString("Name","Harneet");
              editor.commit();


            isblackBrightness = true ; 
            Log.e("Black--","Black=="+isblackBrightness);

            break;
        case R.id.white_brigthness_LL:
            Intent white_britness = new Intent(Setting.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            white_britness.putExtra("bright", "white");
            startActivity(white_britness);
            isblackBrightness = false;
            Log.e("white--","White=="+isblackBrightness);

            SharedPreferences preferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = preferences1.edit();
              editor1.putString("Name","Arun");
              editor1.commit();


            break;

         }
    }
}
```

I am not getting how to do this whether I have to set widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get solution to change the layout of custom keyboard.

**When keyboard first time load onCreateInputView() is called. After that when keyboard open onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) called every time.**

So, now layout of `keyboard(Theme)` have to define in `onCreateInputView()` Like This

```
public KeyboardView mInputView;
public View onCreateInputView() {

    SharedPreferences pre = getSharedPreferences("test", 1);
    int theme = pre.getInt("theme", 1);

    if(theme == 1)
    {
        this.mInputView = (KeyboardView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null);
    }else
    {
        this.mInputView = (KeyboardView) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input_2, null);

    }
    this.mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    this.mInputView.setKeyboard(this.mQwertyKeyboard);
    return this.mInputView;
}
```

and do this in onStartInputView

```
public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);

    setInputView(onCreateInputView());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When the keyboard is shown, the framework calls `onStartInputView`. You can program that function to look at the values of the shared preferences and set the colors/themes appropriately on the keyboard view.

Comment: how i could set diffrent color of keys according to color selected i mean i which class . in SoftKeyboard class ?

Comment: Are you using a default KeyboardView, or a custom keyboard view?  If you're using your own it should be easy but how to do it will depend on how you implemented it.  If you're using the default one-  I don't think any serious keyboard actually uses that.  It doesn't seem to have a lot of customization ability for UI.  The xml allows you to specify a key image, but it doesn't seem to have a runtime function to do so.

Comment: i am using default keyboard view but i want to change beckgroud image for key first time user selects black than color will black if user select white color or background image should  white  control is coming back to onStartInputView method but here insted of change coler whole layout i want change particular images

Comment: i am using  mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.input, null); this for inflate keybord layout